# How to prevent or cancel change detection on global keydown events

Tags: angular

While debugging in Chrome to find the source of some slow response in my application, I noticed in the Peformance tab that holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key generates repeating `keydown` events, each one triggering change detection in Angular. The image below shows the Performance tab for one of them. These events are not useful for my application; I know that nothing changes when <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are pressed by themselves. I only want to know if the key is down when a click event occurs, or when a character or function key is pressed. The extra activity reported in the Performance tab also makes it more difficult to analyze what is of actual interest for my debugging.

Is there a way to prevent or to cancel change detection on global `keydown` events for keys like <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>?

[image]

Comment: Actually i have another approach, you can run your code outside angular zone using `runOutsideAngularZone`, or you can set the change detection strategy in your components to `Onpush`. it will enhance the performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had actually implemented a global capture `keydown` event listener to stop the propagation of the `keydown` events but I had made a mistake identifying the keys. When done correctly, the `globalZoneAwareCallback` part of the processing was eliminated (on the right on the image in the question); the `globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback` part remained.

---

The solution is to stop the propagation of the `keydown` events in a global event listener which does not itself trigger change detection:

- Set a global event listener on the `keydown` event (e.g. in a service)
- Stop the propagation of the event for the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys
- Wrap the call to `window.document.addEventListener` inside `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`. This is important because `addEventListener` triggers Angular change detection, contrary to what I first thought.

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
    window.document.addEventListener("keydown", (event: KeyboardEvent) => { 
        switch (event.which || event.keyCode) {
            case 16:
            case 17: {
                event.stopPropagation();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks to [@ashfaq.p](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219157/ashfaq-p)  and [@Nour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3135151/nour) for the suggestions about `NgZone.runOutsideAngular`.

Answer (score 2):

`Change detection` in angular works using `zone.js`.

`zone.js` provides a method called: `runOutsideAngularZone()`.

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  window.document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this));
});
```

This will allow you to use events like keydown or keyup / mouse move etc outside of angular change detection.

More about this can be found here: [zones in angular](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html#running-code-outside-angulars-zone)

Comment: Thanks for your input! The solution is a combination of using `this.zone.runOutsideAngular` and `addEventListener` to stop the propagation of the `keydown` event. I had seen `runOutsideAngular` but I was under the impression that using `addEventListener` would not trigger change detection. Apparently, that function is [redefined](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/) by Angular to make sure that it does.